# How to output a .cprofile file from script

Tags: python, maya, cprofile, pymel

I'm using the cProfiler in my script. I'd like to output the .cprofile file with results. 
I want to get the output file that is not human readable and later open it in snakeviz. Is that possible?

I cannot use the

```
python -m cProfile -o program.prof my_program.py
```

command, because I'm runing the script with the Python interpreter embedded in the Autodesk Maya software in gui mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've asked the question too soon. I've found that:

```
cProfile.run('function', 'path')
```

can do this